# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Tags: ubuntu

After I removed /home/miniconda3/python3.6 , I can`t use any commands like pip, python , ...

I re-installed such as build-essential,... (found in stackoverflow)
so now I can use pip, python2.7(still can`t use other version of python) in sudo.

I can`t use pip or python in user mode. Here is my error

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007ff61ad5c700 (most recent call first)
```

How can I solve this problem?